# Find IP in error.log

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, batch, batch-file

I'm having trouble building a batch code for find IP in a log using a text filter. For example: this line from Apache web server error.log:

```
[Fri Dec 13 23:32:47.531250 2013] [access_compat:error] [pid 3492:tid 464] [client 68.37.42.231:36925] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /htdocs/cgi-bin/php
```

Find ip using text filter: /htdocs/cgi-bin/php
Output: 68.37.42.231

Is it possible?

Comment: Personally, I'd use these tools: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html. grep/awk/sed would be perfect for this. What have you tried so far? What in particular isn't working for you?

Comment: I tried to use the find command
but I can not apply the filter and the delemitador.

Comment: this will return lines with the string filter you want: find "/htdocs/cgi-bin/php" Drive:\path\to\log\file    -  This won't extract the portion of the line you want - that is a bit harder to do. You might be able to use findstr with a regex for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bockra$ cat /tmp/su 
[Fri Dec 13 23:32:47.531250 2013] [access_compat:error][pid 3492:tid 464] [client 68.37.42.231:36925] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /htdocs/cgi-bin/php

bockra$ awk -F'[: ]' {'print $15'} /tmp/su
68.37.42.231
```

awk can understand multiple delimeters ( -F'[: ]' )
and 'print $15' means your output is string #15 using : and space as a separators

You have to use AWK to make it faster :)
For linux or OsX its usually in dist preinstalled.
For windows you can download it here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Comment: +1 because this is the most easy to understand answer **and** still explains it.

Answer (score 1):

A Powershell version to extract all IP adresses where a predefined text filter matches the same line is:

```
$input = "D:\input.log" 
$output = "D:\ouput.txt"    
$IPregex = "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
$filter = "/htdocs/cgi-bin/php"

gc $input | where { $_ -match $filter} | Select-String -Pattern $IPregex | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
echo([Fri Dec 13 23:32:47.531250 2013] [access_compat:error] [pid 3492:tid 464] [client 68.37.42.231:36925] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /htdocs/cgi-bin/php|grep -Eo "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])"
```

---

```
68.37.42.231
```

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse me, I decided to do in another language where I feel most comfortable.
Many thanks for your examples shown here.

The programming language:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_BASIC

```
nomainwin


[loop]

    'Sleep 500ms
    CALLDLL #kernel32 , "Sleep" , 500 AS Long , rc AS Void

    'Call sub and read last line
    gosub [log]

    'Find by filter in string, if exist abuse call sub
    if instr(lastline$,"xampp/cgi-bin/php") then gosub [htaccess]

    'If ip not exists in htaccess
    gosub [save]

    goto [loop]

    end




'SUBS


[htaccess]
    'Read .htaccess
    open "C:\xampp\htdocs\.htaccess" for input as #handle1
    while EOF(#handle1)=0
        line input #handle1, htaccess$

        if instr(htaccess$,delim2$) then
            exists=1
        else
            exists=0
        end if

    wend
    close #handle1

    RETURN


[log]
    'Sets the maximum size of an array
    dim array2$(999999)

    'Read errorlog file line by line
    open "C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log" for input as #handle2
    while EOF(#handle2)=0
        input #handle2, array2$(errorlog)
        errorlog=errorlog+1
    wend
    close #handle2

    'Put last line in string
    lastline$ = array2$(errorlog-1)

    'Remove text to the string and get ip
    delim$ = word$(lastline$, 4, "]")
    delim1$ = word$(delim$, 1, ":")
    delim2$ = trim$(mid$(delim1$, 10, 50))

    RETURN


[save]
    'Save new entries in .htaccess
    if exists = 0 then

        'Create string and put parameter in front of the ip
        ip$ = "deny from " ; delim2$

        'Read .htaccesst file and put content in string
        open "C:\xampp\htdocs\.htaccess" for input as #f
         htaccesst$ = input$(#f, lof(#f))
        close #f

        'Clean .htaccesst file and put content within the file
        open "C:\xampp\htdocs\.htaccess" for output as #f
         print #f, htaccesst$
         print #f, ip$;
        close #f

    end if

    RETURN
```